# They question or expression

Tags: australian-english

This is a conversation between two girls I heard in audio. Bride and her mate were talking about the groom.

1. Lorrain look what we both are doing. We're picking on poor Des to pieces the night before the wedding.

My question here is which one is appropriate here : what are we both doing or what we both are doing?

Answer (score 2):

Most people would say:

> Look what we are both doing

but it's also correct to say:

> Look what we both are doing.

So either is appropriate.

However, you either **pick on poor Des** (meaning that criticise him, probably unfairly)

or **you pick poor Des to pieces** (meaning that you criticise him severely).

But you DON'T *pick **on** poor Des to pieces*.

Comment: Can i also say "look what are we both doing"

Comment: No. Unless you used *look* as an interjection before a question. For example: **Look! What are we both doing this for?**